# Why doesn't fmap either error id over an Either work?

Tags: haskell, functor

why does the following code not cause an error? Instead, it exits immediately.

```
someAction :: IO (Either String ())
someAction = return $ Left "Error"

main :: IO ()
main = either error id <$> someAction
```

Comment: Sometimes when I mark a question as a duplicate I'm a bit grumpy, because the duplicate is easy to find; often just googling the question as asked finds the duplicate with its answer. But for this one, even I had trouble finding the dupe I wanted, and I mostly remembered the content of both the question (which was somewhat different than yours) *and* the answer (which obviously you don't know)! I don't know if askers feel the dual, like a bit of embarassment or something when their question is marked as a duplicate, but if they do I feel you should absolutely be exempt on this one.

Comment: @DanielWagner I've read somewhere on meta.SO (IIRC) that duplicates shouldn't be thought of as *inherently* "bad" (and therefore the asker shouldn't necessarily feel bad, such as in this case) even though they get closed. They can help people find answers more easily by providing new perspectives on the question. The fact that closing them as duplicates links the questions together helps this process. Of course sometimes, as you said, the answer can be trivially found already, but that's not the case here.

Comment: @DanielWagner none of the dups seem to apply. there is no IO nesting here, the `main` is just `pure (error "error") :: IO ()` which does not print the IO-return value (`()`) as it's supposed to, at the REPL, for some unexplained reason. yet calling `it` right afterwards does cause the error.

Comment: @WillNess Hm. I think all of the dupes apply (maybe that's obvious from my actions...). The shared theme is not nesting of `IO`, but the fact that executing an `IO X` action doesn't do anything special with the resulting `X`.

Comment: @WillNess Actually, reviewing again, I think the third one does not apply after all. I've removed it.

Comment: so what you meant is that returning a pure lazy value from an IO action does not by itself force that value. printing it would force it, but printing does not happen for `()` type values.

Comment: @WillNess All correct, and can be generalized; you can drop "pure lazy" from the first sentence. Returning a value from an IO action does not by itself force that value.

Comment: @DanielWagner I like a little redundancy sometimes, to enhance the descriptiveness. and without "lazy", what's there to "force"? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When an action of type `IO ()` is executed, its return value (the unit) is not evaluated:

- [In the interactive prompt](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#i-o-actions-at-the-prompt): "GHCi will print the result of the I/O action if (and only if) [...] The result type is not `()`."
- When running a compiled program (I have verified this but can't find a reference! Feel free to edit in).

`error`, unlike `ioError`, is presenting as a pure function of type `String -> a`. To simplify your example:

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = pure $ error "error"
```

Running `main` as an IO action performs all side-effects (of which there are none) but doesn't do anything with the return value, so it is not evaluated.

This, however, will error, as `print` evaluates its argument (even `()`):

```hs
main >>= print
```

Comment: Hi Koterpillar, appreciate for your quick response, already marked your response as answer to my question. 

Comment: "When an action of type IO () is executed, its return value (the unit) is not evaluated." the question was / still is, why? why `pure (error "error") :: IO ()` doesn't try to print `error "error" :: ()` at the REPL as it's supposed to, right away? -- while calling `it` afterwards does try  to print it, and indeed causes the error.  as does `pure (error "error") :: IO Int`  try to print the `error "error" :: Int` value right away (or with any other type for `Int`), and errors out as expected.

Comment: @WillNess All `IO ()` actions behave that way at the REPL -- i.e. the `()` is not printed. This is the [intended, documented behavior](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.3/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html).

Comment: @DanielWagner thanks for the link. So this is the answer, and should probably appear in an answer.